Rspec expectation error: reading hash argument as keyword arguments
I'm in the middle of an update to Rails 7.1.3 and I've run into an interesting issue.
I have an initialize which has one positional argument (which defaults to an empty hash) and some keyword arguments: eg.
  def initialize(opts = {}, foo: :bar)

And I'm mocking out the initialize with just the options hash in my specs:
  options = {cow: "over", moon: "under"}
  expect(Thing).to(receive(:new).with(options))

This results in an unexpected argument error, where it appears the members of the options hash have been read as keyword arguments:
RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: Invalid keyword arguments provided: cow, moon

How can I make this mock read the hash as a hash in the position of the first argument?

Minimal case to reproduce:
class Thing
  def initialize(opts = {}, foo: "bar")
  end
end

require "rspec"

describe Thing do
  let(:options) { {cow: "over", moon: "below"} }

  it "mocks out the initialize" do
    expect(Thing).to(receive(:new).with(options))

    pp Thing.new(options)
  end
end

And versions of my rspec-related gems:
rails (7.1.3)
rspec (3.13.0)
rspec-core (3.13.0)
rspec-expectations (3.13.0)
rspec-mocks (3.13.0)
rspec-rails (6.1.0
rspec-retry (0.6.2)
rspec-support (3.13.0)


Edit: Things I've tried:

Making it a variable and passing that to with
Adding keyword arguments after it in both the with and new calls
Removing the default empty hash argument

This actually passes the test, but it feels like we should be able to have a default here.




I can't reproduce your error. Can you check that the "Minimal case to reproduce" actually does reproduce it? If you're certain, then could you clarify which ruby version you are using?

Note that your question has nothing to do with rails. It might relate to specific versions of rspec/ruby, but not rails. Because there is no mention/use of rails anywhere in this code.
